# search line break in several tables and get the rowid

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a list of tables and columns stored into "CAMPOS_BL_FS_050321_2" and i want to loop through that tables, only can i get one rowid for table, i need create an array to stored all rowid from a table, but i can't get the right code to works

```
DECLARE
  match_count varchar2(30 byte);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME,DBLINK FROM CAMPOS_BL_FS_050321_2) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   'select rowid FROM ' || t.SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || t.TABLE_NAME || t.DBLINK ||' WHERE instr(' || t.COLUMN_NAME  || ', chr(10)) > 0 and rownum=1'
   INTO match_count;
    IF match_count IS NOT null THEN
        insert into log_tabla values(t.COLUMN_NAME ,t.TABLE_NAME, match_count);
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  More critically, you are wide open to SQL injection here.  Suggest you research and implement prepared SQL for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what error you're getting (please do next time), just that you can't get it to work so this is just my 2 cents.

match_count is a *scalar* value. It can hold a single value - 1 rowid in your case. But your select statement can/will have multiple rows so you need to store that in a variable that can hold an array of values. In pl/sql that is called a *collection* - you can read all about that [here][1]. Typically you create a `TYPE` in your block of the records you want to store and use that:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rowid_t IS TABLE OF rowid INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  l_rowids rowid_t;
BEGIN
  SELECT rowid BULK COLLECT INTO l_rowids FROM h_item_all;
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_rowids.COUNT 
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(l_rowids(i));
  END LOOP;

  FOR t IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME,DBLINK FROM CAMPOS_BL_FS_050321_2) 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select rowid FROM ' || t.SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || t.TABLE_NAME || t.DBLINK ||' WHERE instr(' || t.COLUMN_NAME  || ', chr(10)) > 0 and rownum=1'
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_rowids;

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_rowids.COUNT 
  LOOP
    insert into log_tabla values(t.COLUMN_NAME ,t.TABLE_NAME, l_rowids(i)); 
  END LOOP;   
  COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: it´s works, thanks Koen, sorry for not specifying the problem so well, what happened is that I did not know how to leave the data of the variable in an array